# Update table if join table does not have rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables which has relationships and I trying to update base table if there are no records in the child table.

Table1:

```
id value
1  abc
2  xyz
```

Table2:

```
id table1_id
1  1
2  1
```

So in this case I want to update table1 id 2 to `pqr` as it does not have associated rows in table2. For id 1 nothing happens.

I tried this way but this is completely wrong

```
update table1  set value = 'pqr'
    from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on count(t2.table1_id) < 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the rows of `table1` with `id`s that don't have a match in `table2` in the column `table1_id` then you can do it with a `LEFT JOIN` and update the unmatched rows:

```
update t1  
set t1.value = 'pqr'
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 
on t2.table1_id = t1.id 
where t2.table1_id is null
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f6bef7e7a070d87be9182f19d527887b).
Results:

```
> id | value
> -: | :----
>  1 | abc  
>  2 | pqr
```

Comment: This updated the table1 id 2 instead of id 1 as per the demo

Comment: Yes because this is what you ask in your question. Which is wrong: the title or the demo?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Title is right. Updating the question

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

```
update table1  
set value = 'pqr'
from table1 t1 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.table1_id = t1.id);
```

Although this assumes you're asking the question in the title, not the one in the test of your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1
SET value = 'pqr'
WHERE id IN (SELECT t1.id FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1_id)
```